# Why I can´t access my -u and -s flag in Gobuster

Tags: brute-force

I was trying to use the `gobuster` tool but I came across this error that I can't find an answer no matter how much I search. How am I supposed to be able to use these two flags with `gobuster`?

```
──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ gobuster -s 200 -u http://192.168.56.8/amagicbridgeappearsatthechasm/ -w usr/share/wordlists
Error: unknown shorthand flag: 's' in -s
                                                                                                                                             
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ gobuster -u  http://192.168.56.8/amagicbridgeappearsatthechasm/ -w usr/share/wordlists
Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'u' in -u
```

Comment: Always make sure that you read the [documentation](https://github.com/OJ/gobuster) of the tools you use. And look up the `--help` on commands. The answer to this is in both places.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer is in the tool documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of websites refer to older versions of gobuster that had global -s and -u flags. Even on the Kali website are screenshots of multiple versions showing conflicting information. On https://www.kali.org/tools/gobuster/, the topmost screenshot shows v1.2 and a command line similar to yours.

In current versions of gobuster, these flags are not global but tied to specific commands of gobuster. See the lower image on the Kali page linked above.

In your case, use the `dir` command of gobuster so that the command becomes
`gobuster dir -s 200 -u http://192.168.56.8/amagicbridgeappearsatthechasm/ -w usr/share/wordlists`

On a side note, is this really a local path to a single file called `wordlists`, or does it miss both a leading `/` and an actual filename?

Comment: tank for the response and the wordlists was just to exemplify.